# Cannot set session cookie max age in Kubernetes Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, kubernetes, docker-compose, jsessionid

I have a Spring Boot (1.5.8) webapp, with several other Spring Boot services, all deployed to AWS. The webapp module is deployed to two EC2 instances managed by an Elastic Load Balancer. The whole system is orchestrated by Kubernetes.

I'm trying to set the session cookie max age to work around a problem, as suggested here: [Spring-SAML Endless redirect loop after a successful authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756986/spring-saml-endless-redirect-loop-after-a-successful-authentication)

When I run on my local machine using Docker Compose, all I do is set `server.session.cookie.max-age` in the webapp's `application.yml` and it works.

The same thing doesn't work in the Kubernetes-managed system. The webapp has an env actuator endpoint set up and I can see that the max-age setting was applied, but the cookie still has "session" expiration.

The session cookie is named `JSESSIONID` on my local machine, but just `SESSION` on the Kubernetes cluster. Why is that? Is the session cookie managed at some higher level in that system, like by the load balancer or Kubernetes itself? I'm pretty lost at this point, so any suggestions would help.

Comment: > "The webapp module is deployed to two EC2 instances managed by an Elastic Load Balancer. The whole system is orchestrated by Kubernetes."

It is very unclear what you mean by that. If your app is deployed as a Kubernetes pod, just say so. Possibly you deployed several instances, maybe old instances are running and still matched by your Kubernetes service, and therefore `/actuator/env` and the real requests are inconsistent.

It looks like your `SESSION` cookie isn't Spring's session cookie but comes from somewhere else, but only you have access to look for the origin.

Comment: OK, my app is deployed as a Kubernetes pod ... or really ten pods, two of which are instances of the webapp. I've redeployed recently, so I don't think there's an issue with old instances. My question boils down to where _should_ I look for the origin of the `SESSION` cookie? I've looked at the ELB configuration and the Kubernetes deployment yml files, but I'm not even sure what to look for.

Comment: First, you should really update to Spring Boot 2.x. Then, how is your Spring Boot app executed inside the container? Is it an executable Jar with the embedded servlet container? If so, which one (default tomcat or one of the alternatives)? Or is it deployed as .war file into a different servlet container? By default, nothing in Spring or the embedded container leads to such behavior, unless you configure it explicitly. Other places to look: is there a Kubernetes ingress controller? Or a service mesh with something similar? If not, there is not much left but the ELB.

Comment: Thanks! That's good advice. I'd prefer to be using Spring Boot 2 too, but unfortunately it's not my decision. It's the executable Jar with embedded Tomcat. I  don't think there's an ingress controller, but I'll look more at that. I'm not familiar with a service mesh, but I'll research that as well. It seems like the ELB can be configured with sticky sessions and that produces a cookie, but it's `AWSELB`, not `SESSION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turned out that the session is being managed by Spring due to `spring.session.store-type` being set to `redis` in the integration environments. It's `none` in my local build, which means Tomcat manages the session instead. Sorry, I didn't mean to obfuscate that. I just didn't know what to look for. The default session cookie name for a Spring-managed session is `SESSION`, while for Tomcat, it's `JSESSIONID`, so I was at least right about that being the key to the mystery.

There don't seem to be properties for configuring the Spring session cookie, but I found this explanation about how to configure it in code: [Spring Session - Custom Cookie](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html)